# How to get assert_raise to handle exception subclasses

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, exception, assertions

Sometimes I would like a unit test to confirm that some code raises an exception, without knowing the exception class exactly.  For example, to confirm that it raises an exception which is a `kind_of?(StandardError)`, I'd like to write this:

```
assert_raise StandardError do
  my_method
end
```

This assertion passes if the exception is an instance of `StandardError`, but fails if the exception is an instance of a *subclass* of `StandardError`.  My best solution is this:

```
begin
  my_method
rescue StandardError => error
  return
end
assert false, "no error from my_method"
```

`rescue` does handle exception subclasses the way I want, so this works.  But it's a little awkward.  Any better ideas?

This is the Test::Unit::Assertions module in Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [rubyforge bugtracker ticket **[#8716] Add option to Test::Unit::Assertions#assert_raise to allow subclasses** from 2007(!)](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=8716&group_id=426&atid=1700) this is a feature request that's still open.

You could monkeypatch the functionality if you need it realy badly.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same as what you started with, but is a little more self explanatory IMO:

```
begin
  my_method
rescue => e
  # Could be any number of error classes: 
  # HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError, SocketError, etc.
  assert e.class.ancestors.include?(StandardError), "Expected my_method to raise a subclass of StandardError, but #{e.class} was raised"
  return
end

# Force the test to fail if no error was raised
assert false, "Expected my_method to raise a subclass of StandardError, but no error was raised"
```

Comment: Why `e.class.ancestors.include?(StandardError)`? What about `e.is_a? StandardError`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the exception is optional in [`assert_raise`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_raise)

> Tests if the given block raises an exception. Acceptable exception types maye be given as optional arguments.

You should be able to write

```
assert_raise { my_method }
```

Comment: But then the test will pass if (say) a SignalException is raised, right?  That's an Exception, but it's not a StandardError, so I want that to fail.

Comment: I don't get the point. Do you want assert_raise to check if the error is an instance of `StandardError`?

Comment: Yes, StandardError or a subclass thereof.  I'll edit to make this clearer.